# Can GhostScript generate JPEG2000 compressed PDFs?

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, jpeg2000

I'm seeing mixed information about GhostScript's handling of JPEG2000. Can GS generate PDFs with JP2 (JPX) compressed image content?

If so, what are the appropriate arguments?

Comment: it does work with img2pdf: `img2pdf -o output.pdf input.jp2` (also imagemagick convert fails, it seems to convert the JP2 to a JPG image, so the output.pdf is much bigger)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer here is 'no'.

Comment: Very disappointing to hear, but thanks for the concise answer.

Comment: @KenS At least reference a bug number from gs to qualify this post as an answer

Comment: malat, what bug number ? In what way is my answer incomplete without a bug number ? Its a simple question with an equally simple answer. As explanation; the JPEG2000 specification is (possibly was) encumbered with patents. Decoding was available as a royalty free license, encoding required commercial licensing which is, obviously, incompatible with open-source. The patents may have expired by now (haven't checked), but the software hasn't changed.